# Puppeteer doesn't work correctly in headless: true

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I have a test case that selects publication from list and clicks retweet button on it to trigger modal which is then inserted into DOM and has 2 buttons, Confirm and Cancel.

In headless: false - everything works as expected, modal is displayed and clicked:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrmA5.png

In headless: true - modal is never opened:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnpnE.png

Test Code

```
test('should repost conversation', async () => {
    const options = {
      showOwnedBtn: 'showOwned-link',
      ideaSelector: 'searchbar-idea',
      retweetBtn: 'retweet-button',
      selectedPublication: 'The looming challenge to South Korea competitiveness',
      titleSelector: 'publicationTitle-link',
      repostBtn: 'repost-button',
    }
    await login.user(users.hubert, 'wubs', path);
    await navbar.removeFilter(options.showOwnedBtn, path);
    await navbar.searchFilter(options.ideaSelector, path, null);

    await publication.selectPublicationRetweetByTitle(options.titleSelector, options.selectedPublication, path);
    await page.waitForSelector(options.repostBtn)
    await modal.confirm(options.repostBtn, path);

    await navbar.goto('flow', path);

    await screenshot.take(path);
    await logout.user(users.hubert, 'wubs', path);
  });
```

Problematic method:

```
async selectPublicationRetweetByTitle(selector, text, path) {
    const retweetSelector = dataAutomation('retweet-button');
    const pub = dataAutomation('publication')
    const publicationSelector = await page.$$(pub);
    let selected = null;
    for (const publication of publicationSelector) {
      const pubTitleSelector = await publication.$('[data-automation="publicationTitle-link"]');
      const pubTitle = await pubTitleSelector.getProperty('innerText');
      const titleText = await pubTitle.jsonValue();
      if (titleText === text){
        selected = await publication.$(retweetSelector);
      }
    }
    await screenshot.take(path);
    await selected.click();

    await screenshot.take(path);
  }
```

Comment: [elementHandle.jsonValue()][1] returns object so comparing with string should return false. did you try to console.log this value?


https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-elementhandlejsonvalue

Comment: I debugged it and logged it, it returns string in both headless and headfull.